# Update 1 row in a table that has 5 columns, and make other columns have the old value if they're not changed

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with 10 columns, and I have 1 row too.

I want to update only one row and not the others
If I update just one, the other ones will have the default value which is the expected behavior

Is there a way so that I change only a row and still have all the other rows preserve the old values?

I don't want to use a lot of resources for this thing so I wish there's something built-in or something

TL;DR:- How can I update a row and have the other rows stay the same?

I'm using `MySQL`

Comment: If your table has only one row, why are you concerned about other rows?  Sample data and desired results would really help.  And the title says 5 columns but the body of the question says 10.  Very confusing.

Comment: Cause I care about the data in them, also, I don't want to have more than 1 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `update` statement lets you control both the rows being updated and the columns.  Usually the rows are defined by the `where` clause and the `columns` by the `set`:

```
update t
    set col4 = <some value>
    where col1 = <some value>;
```

If the `where` clause is using the table's primary key with an equality condition, then only one row is updated, and only the specified columns in that row change.

Answer (score 1):

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM X )
UPDATE [Table] SET...
ELSE
INSERT INTO [Table]